# Edit network connection in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8.1

In Windows 8 one could edit a connection settings by right clicking on a connection and selecting edit while on the Networks taskbar menu.

Also in other versions of Windows, there was a list of connections so that they could be removed or changed even when not in range (wifi). [1](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/manage-wireless-network-profiles)

Both these features appear to be moved or removed. How can one accomplish these vital tasks in Windows 8.1 (without using the console)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best solution I found: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/wifi-profile-manager-windows-8

This app was made just for this problem. Not not usable for touch trough.